# Query id from one collection and value of id from another collection - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to query `id` from one collection and value of that id from another collection in a same method. I trying a old school method which takes lot of time to loop , check condition and send back response. Is there is any efficient way to do it.

**My Collection**

**a.model.ts**

```
    [{
      "_id": "5e0987d7f9b2473264f64565",
      "empId": "5de60be5707fba2750c0770c",
      "role": :emp,
      "createdAt": "2019-12-30T05:15:03.595Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-12-30T05:15:03.595Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e0987d7f9b2473264f64565",
      "role": :emp,
      "empId": "5de60be5707fba2750c2384c",
      "createdAt": "2019-12-30T05:15:03.595Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-12-30T05:15:03.595Z",
      "__v": 0
    }]
```

**b.model.ts**

```
[{
  "_id": "5de60be5707fba2750c0770c",
  "name": "abc",
  "age": "25",
  "updatedAt": "2019-12-30T05:15:03.595Z",
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": "5de60be5707fba2750c0770c",
  "name": "xyz",
  "age": "29",
  "updatedAt": "2019-12-30T05:15:03.595Z",
  "__v": 0
}]
```

**get.ts**

```
a.find({
    role: "emp"
}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err)
    } else {
        data.forEach(element => {
            b.find({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(element.empId)
            }, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    res.send(result);
                }


            })
        });
    }
})
```

I have got all the data which matches `role:emp` from `a` and looped to get the empId so that I can loop the `b` and send the details as response. Is there is any efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show schema.

Comment: are you using ref in schema for empId in a.model? if yes then check mongoose query a.find({
    role: "emp"
},populate('empId').exec()